# crossdomain.xml not working (Flash/Flex)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I want to access a script on another domain(I have access to this other domain too).
I added a very permissive crossdomain.xml file on the root of the domain

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

crossdomain.xml [link](http://page1traffic.net/crossdomain.xml)

This is my AS3 code

```
var domainsCSV:String=domains.join(",");
var url:String="https://page1traffic.net/keywordxpapi/testscript.php";
var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
urlRequest.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.domains=domainsCSV;
urlRequest.data=variables;
var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onError);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
function onComplete(e:Event):void{
}

function onError(e:Event=null):void{
    trace(e);
    if(e is SecurityErrorEvent){
        trace(SecurityErrorEvent(e).text);
    }
    Alert.show("Error from script "+e);

}
```

I get the SecurityErrorEvent 2048 , I checked in firebug and I see the browser reciving the xml response so I have no idea why I can't make cross domains calls.

Comment: http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html#allow-access-from-secure in case your swf file is from insecure protocol (http) you need to add _secure="false"_ to the _allow-access-from_ node

Comment: Are you trying to load it from Amazon S3 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>`